# Extend Group model from django.contrib.auth.model, remove unique constarint on name and add unique_together name, organization fields

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to extend the django Group model and organization field to it for creating permission based roles specific to organization. Basically I want to remove the unique constraint on the name field, add a field called organization, and make name and organization unique together.

I tried this

```
class MyGroup(Group):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'organization',)
```

I am getting error 
**users.MyGroup.name: (models.E006) The field 'name' clashes with the field 'name' from model 'auth.group'.**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to monkey patch the `Group` model which is going to be hacky.

I'd probably approach it by doing the following:

- Monkey patch the Group model in some new app called `contrib.auth`.
- Resolve the migration problems - hopefully you can create them in one of your project's apps migrations directories, ideally `contrib.auth`.
- Monkey patch the GroupAdmin view in the new `contrib.auth` app.
- Verify the actual authorization works with the new unique constraint. Some lookups may assume that `name` is unique. You'll need to monkey patch/modify/avoid these.

Again, I feel like this approach can't be the right one. You may be better off looking for a non-core library to solve this or rolling your own.